# visual basic data base picture

Tags: vb.net, image, ms-access

HOW i insert image in microsoft access and how to call in visual basic

Answer (score 1):

You should detail a bit more on how you plan to store the image.
**Option a**: Normally, you will need an OLE field, in which the user will right-click and choose "insert object". He can then either have that object linked to the source or not.
**Option b**: you could also decide to store the UNC path to the image in a text field.

Option a is not recommended because it is very heavy and unefficient.
Option b, if your requirements allow it, is much lighter, because Access (you did not specify your version) is very unefficient in storing ole objects, and they consume a huge space in you db.

You can Google for "Access VBA ole object", and you will find usable info like these:
http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-access/1629613-open-ole-object-vba.html and http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=154434

Comment: Access 2010 features enhanced image management : http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/store-images-in-a-database-HP005280225.aspx

Comment: I think storing images in the database is a bad idea, particularly in Access, because of the weird OLE stuff that's wrapped around them. You can certainly store binary data in a BLOB field, but it's more complicated. But first of all, I'd ask whether or not it's really the right approach to store the images in the database at all, rather than storing them in the file system and keeping only a pointer to the file in the database.